# Excel - 24h on one sheet to 12h on another sheet

Tags: excel

I have a budget Excel Workbook that I use to calculate my staffing requirements.
I use  100-2400 for my hours in the spread sheet I use this formula in a helper cell `=IF((E3-D3)>0,(E3-D3)-50,0)`to remove the 30min lunch break from wages

Problem is my Students are confused reading the schedule of 800-1600 / 900-1700 / 1225-2025  etc.
This month I manually put the details from the schedule into a calendar and converted the times to HH:MM AM/PM,  I would like to create a calendar on another sheet of the work book and use a formula to pull data from my employee columns in each month and populate the hours they work in an AM/PM format.

I am at a loss even what I should be looking up.  Ideally though might not be possible I'd like a single Calendar work sheet where I would enter at the top of the work sheet the employee name and then the month and it would pull the data  I could print and then do the next employee

Currently all employee names live in the first Worksheet of the work book and all additional worksheets pull the name from that cell, every worksheet the employee is in the same columns.   DEF/JKL/MNO/...... /CMCNCO

But that might be a pipe dream,  I will make a calendar for each employee if I can get a formula that converts my 800 to 8am and 1600 to 4pm

EDIT

This is the sample of the spread sheet I'm dealing with  Output could be exactly the same except with AM/PM hours Yellow text is result of previously mentioned formula

[image: This is the sample of the spread sheet I'm dealing with Output could be exactly the same except with AM/PM hours Yellow text is result of previously mentioned formula]

Comment: This can be done... how is your 800 store, it is eight hundred in an integer or is it 800 as a string? or is it stored as time and when you set format to general is displays as a decimal point?

Comment: `at a loss even what I should be looking up` something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&espv=2&q=excel+convert+24+hour+time+to+12+hour+time&oq=excel+convert+24+hour+to+12+hour+&gs_l=serp.1.1.0i22i30l8.198528.198528.0.201029.1.1.0.0.0.0.74.74.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.73._zDhFraU1YE)?

Comment: You should also be aware that excel officially only works with 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 as valid times.  24:00 is not a valid time...there are some function within spreadsheet formulas that do work with 24th hour but not all.

Comment: You've not indicated exactly how you're storing your *100-2400* values, so how are we supposed to suggest how you could convert them to something else? If it's an integer value, it's a simple integer division and modulo to convert to hours and minutes, if the hours are 12 or more its PM, and if the hours are greater than 12 you subtract 12. It's a little sad your students can't grasp it, though.

Comment: @stephenBB81 and example layout of what you describe or what you want to achieve would have been helpful.  at worst even a screen shot showing what you want to achieve would help.

Comment: @KenWhite  24 -12 is should not be 12 PM in excel.  24 is a special case which is 12 AM or 00:00  but yes as a general rule of thumb correct.

Comment: @ForwardEd: 2400 should not exist. Valid time IMO is 0000-235959. Correct the poster's use of it. :-) The poster also loses the time between 0000 and 0100, so I guess they have a 23 hour day.

Comment: @findwindow  I did that exact google search before coming here.  It turned up nothing of use.

Comment: @ForwardEd Time is stored as an Integer   Hence  1225 to signify 12:15,  Also as far as I know the Only way that my formula =IF((E3-D3)>0,(E3-D3)-50,0) could work is if it was an integer,  though I could have been wrong.   From a layout  really Just columns that have 800 = 8:00am is all I care about how it looks I can tweet.

Comment: @KenWhite Trust me  I find it ridiculous  as well that the kids didn't know the 24h clock,  I'm hiring University Students,  and shifts are between 8am and 8:30pm   all shift start in an AM and end in a PM.  My time to play with excel is maybe 10min a week, So tweaking this to accommodate the students is killing me.   Because I wanted the AM/PM in the new cell I didn't think I could change integer 1600 to 4:00pm by removing 12,  nor how to turn 1225 into 12:15pm

Comment: @StephenBB81  a screenshot of your layout would be very helpful.  We have no clue what the contents of E3 or D3 are.  Sample data is always better but a screen shot can do in a pinch.

Comment: @ForwardEd you're fast!  I was uploading the screen shot while you replied

Comment: @StephenBB81 Wish I had seen the screen shot prior to answering

Comment: @ForwardEd even without the screenshot your solution helped, if I didn't ask such a poorly worded question and have all my rep taken away you'd see I've upvoted you

Comment: @StephenBB81  The background info on the ultimate goal of creating a calendar was a bit of a red herring.  I tend to agree with supplying back ground info cause it can shape the answers dues to other considerations.  In this case your question was really how to convert 1250 as an int to excel time format of 12:30 AM.  Ahh hindsight...anyone have it for foresight yet?

Comment: If I had Foresight I would have not said "sure I can create an excel spreadsheet for that"  when asked about creating student schedules haha Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=TIME(LEFT(RIGHT("0"&D3,4),2),RIGHT(D3,2)/100*60,0)
```

The above will convert your time from your format of hours and minutes where 15 minutes is represented 25.  I want to say hundredths of an hour but not sure that is the right term.

Basically we are using the build TIME function which requests three arguments as integers in descending order:  hours, minutes and seconds.

```
=TIME(HOUR, MINUTES, SECONDS)
```

So in order to determine your hours, we need the first 1 or 2 digits.  I made the assumption you do not have a preceding 0 in from of 8 for 8am.  So the first thing I did was to tag on a preceeding zero to your time regardless of what time it is, then I pulled the right 4 characters to tell me the full time.  From this I proceeded with the LEFT function and pulled the leading two characters.  Since this is excel and it prefers the 24 hour clock I do not need to do anything in terms of AM PM as the 24 hour clock takes care of that for me.

In order to determine the minutes, I pulled the 2 right most characters and divided them by 100 to get the fraction of an hour, and then multiplied by 60 to determine which minute of the hour we were looking at.

As for seconds, I assumed you were not getting to that level of detail and just set it to 0.

After that format the cell containing the formula to TIME instead of general.  Choose 24 hour or 12 hour what ever suits your needs.

In the screen shot below which shows proof of concept, column E and column F have the exact same formulas in them.  The difference is the formatting of the cell.

[image]

EDIT  Error checking

in order not to display error you can wrap the equation in an IFERROR statement

```
=IFERROR(TIME(LEFT(RIGHT("0"&D3,4),2),RIGHT(D3,2)/100*60,0),"")
```

Comment: Thank you!,  That adding the Zero first makes a lot of sense and I didn't think to do that.  When I drop your formula in  it outputs properly I just need to ensure that first I am checking if the cell actually had data in it so I don't get #VALUE when they don't   but this is a great place to get me started

Comment: Looking at your example data.  column D and E are data entry?  If so have you considered rejigging them so they accept time entry, and then adjusting your fomula in F to work with time instead of integers?  I realize the time you spend on this is a pain.  Working with time formulas would allow whoever is doing the data entry to do it in what ever format they are most comfortable with and then whoerver is reading can also set things to display in whatever format they are comfortable with.  and FYI, just because your have a cell formatted as AM/PM does not prevent you from entering 24 hour time.

Comment: @StephenBB81 see edit for error checking

Comment: D & E are data Entry yes.  This sheet serves 2 purposes,  Giving my students their monthly schedule,  AND giving accounting/sharehoulders details reports of how money is being spent,  and sadly all budget spreadsheets use integers as time,  eventually I'll be tying this sheet into my massive budget sheet and having integers will make that evil process easier.  I thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you store your data as actual time values you can format them however you want.

Put the formula `=time(6,0,0)` in cell A1 and copy it down a few rows.

Right click on cells to go to format cells>number>custom

A1 probably defaults to h:mm AM/PM which shows 6:00 AM

Format B1 as HHMM it shows 0600

Format C1 as 0.00 it shows 0.25 (excel treats 1 day = 1.00 so 6 am is 0.25)

Format D1 as [hh]:mm it shows as 06:00 with the added benefit that hours can go above 24 (which you probably don't need in this case.)